# jQuery DataTables adding dynamic columns

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

- Requirements: Draw a datatable with JSON object returned by a
  webservice.
- Constraints: Number of columns is not known.

My implementation looks like the following, but I'm not sure where/how to define columns after receiving JSON from ajax request.

```
$("#reportTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/path/that/returns/json",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": { "formatType": "json", "dispatchType": "api" , "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{ csrf_token }}"},
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
            console.log(json); //can i set my column definition here?
        },
    },
    "columns":["Do i need to even add this?"],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "pageLength": 50
});
```

This is the format of the JSON returned, Note that properties may vary:

Result 1:

```
    [
       {
          "fname":"Bruce",
          "lname":"Wayne",
          "id":"BatMan"
       },
       {
          "fname":"Steve",
          "lname":"Rogers",
          "id":"CptAmerica"
       },
       {
          "fname":"Tony",
          "lname":"Stark",
          "id":"IronMan"
       }
    ]
```

Result 2:

```
    [
       {
          "company":"Wayne Enterprices",
          "owner":"Bruce Wayne"
       },
       {
          "company":"Stark Industries",
          "owner":"Tony Stark"
       },
       {
          "company":"SpaceX",
          "owner":"Elon Musk"
       }
    ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: hey @vignz.pie, have you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same issue and trying to get the solution for the hours...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete example of how to achieve this:

```js
      /**
     * Get random dataset
     * */
    const getData = () => {
        let data = [
            [
                {
                    "fname":"Bruce",
                    "lname":"Wayne",
                    "id":"BatMan"
                },
                {
                    "fname":"Steve",
                    "lname":"Rogers",
                    "id":"CptAmerica"
                },
                {
                    "fname":"Tony",
                    "lname":"Stark",
                    "id":"IronMan"
                }
            ],[
                {
                    "company":"Wayne Enterprices",
                    "owner":"Bruce Wayne"
                },
                {
                    "company":"Stark Industries",
                    "owner":"Tony Stark"
                },
                {
                    "company":"SpaceX",
                    "owner":"Elon Musk"
                }
            ]
        ];

        let index = Math.round(Math.random()); // 1 or 0

        return data[index];
    }

    /**
     * This function acts as an ajax call
     */
    const getAjaxData = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let data = getData();

            return resolve(data);
        })
    }

    const buildHeader = (data) => {
        let firstRow = data[0] || [],
            keys = Object.keys(firstRow);

        return keys.map(key => ({
            data: key,
            name: key
        }))
    }
    
    /**
    * Initialize datatable with the data
    **/
    const buildDataTable = (columns, data) => {
        console.log({columns, data});

        $("#sample-table").DataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: columns,
            pageLength: 100,
            processing: true,
        });
    }

    // main
    $(window).ready(() => {
    
        // simulate ajax call
        getAjaxData().then(data => {
            let columns = buildHeader(data);

            buildDataTable(columns, data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Couldn't fetch the data", err);
        })
    })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <table id="sample-table" class="table">

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

**Additional:**

In addition, which was my exact case, if you have server-side rendering initially, and then want to use ajax for further pages, just generate the html table including `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements, make sure all header cells match the names, then initialize datatable using:

```
$("#sample-table").DataTable({
    ajax: `/path/to/api/data`,
    columns: columns,
    pageLength: pageLength,
    processing: true,
    deferRender: true, /* this means we already have the first page data*/
    deferLoading: totalRecords, /*total all records*/
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    searching: false,
    info:     false
});
```

**Note:**

Issues with the `Requested unknown parameter 'foo.bar' for row y, column x.`

Using `something.foo.bar` as a column name in a case when the source data is flattened, for example, source data:

```
{
   "something.foo.bar": "some text",
   "something.foo.bar.baz": 123
}
```

will give an error, because it will try to find `bar` inside `foo` inside `something`, which doesn't exist. In this case, you need to replace `.` with something else.

Answer (score -1):

```
This is a quick post about how to modify your JSON returned objects before sending them to the tables using DataTables.js. 
In this example I am using a flat array for my JSON objects. For more uses for data sources in AJAX visit http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/

The Code

$('#example_table').DataTable({
  //'deferRender': false,
  'ajax'       : {
    "type"   : "POST",
    "url"    : http://yourURLhere.com/path/to/your/script,
    "dataSrc": function (json) {
      var return_data = new Array();
      for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){
        return_data.push({
          'title': json[i].title,
          'url'  : '<img src="' + json[i].url + '">',
          'date' : json[i].date
        })
      }
      return return_data;
    }
  },
  "columns"    : [
    {'data': 'url'},
    {'data': 'title'},
    {'data': 'date'}
  ]
});


So the dataSrc property can have a function passed to it. The dataSrc property contains the returned information given from your post request. Now, since we are using a flat array like this:

[
  {
   title : 'example_title',
   url   : 'example_url',
   date  : 'example_date'
  },
  {
   title : 'example_title2',
   url   : 'example_url2',
   date  : 'example_date2'
  },... and so on...
]
```

[a shortened version of the standard arrays.txt as the data source and simply added the column names definition.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29260/dynamic-column-headers-via-ajax)
 Here the solution is to change the response. Earlier it was {"userid":"manohar", "password":"1234"}, now I have changed it to [["manohar", "1234"]]. Then in js file

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'userController?action=list',
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var table_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var table = $('#usermaintenancetable').DataTable( {
            data: table_data
     });
  } 
});


    So here the response is in String format and I have change it to JSON using JSON.parse() then passed this as data to data table.
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, I won't be knowing JSON properties until ajax response arrives. Hence, I cannot define columns like that of your answer.

Comment: I have modified the answer .please have a look

Comment: Thanks, Brajesh, but again, I won't be knowing the length of each JSON sent in the response. I've updated the question to emphasize that every time an ajax request is made, the response will alter. Let me know if I have to elaborate further.